# Bootstrap 4 pagination not working correctly in Larave 8

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

The pagination is not working correctly, the arrows are all wrong.
The CSS of Bootstrap  4 it's not been applied in the pagination of the table in my HTML.

print here: https://prnt.sc/v82bfa

My code:

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" />
```

The table:

```
 <table class="table">
        <thead>
            ...
        <thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->nome }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->preco }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->descricao }}</td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        <tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the arrows are all wrong"? Are they no longer styled properly? Is the markup generated as expected?

Comment: The arrows are big and out of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel dropped default for Bootstrap pagination in Laravel 8

If you want to use bootstrap for pagination

You need to add

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

in a service provider.

Go to AppServiceProvider.php and add `Paginator::useBootstrap();` in the boot method

Comment: Here are the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#using-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Comment: @jeanpdf mark this answer as accepted, so we can consider the question has solved